# How to optimise DB model for fast LIKE query with wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sqlperformance

I would like to know what the most efficient way is to optimise a database model in SQL server for querying with LIKE with wildcards in the beginning. I'm not a DB expert, so all advice on use of indexes or other optimisations is welcome.

**Situation:**
I have a table 'Product' with following columns:

```
ShortNameEN (varchar(50))
ShortNameFR (varchar(50))
ShortNameDE (varchar(50))
ShortNameNL (varchar(50))
LongNameEN (varchar(250))
LongNameFR (varchar(250))
LongNameDE (varchar(250))
LongNameNL (varchar(250))
```

This table contains 300000+ records.

I need to write a select statement to find records that **contain** a searchstring (only in ShortNameEN).
My query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE ShortNameEN LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

Of course, this query is terribly slow. Adding indexes on ShortNameEN will not help, since they won't be used due to the first wildcard.

**Question 1:** Would it make sense to separate the ShortNameEN column from the rest of the table? I have no idea about disk access/row sizes/page sizes and how this would affect performance. Maybe there are other file-system related optimisations that could improve performance here?

**Temporary solution**

I found a creative 'trigram' solution, but with quite some impact on my model. For this I created a second table 'ProductNameFragments' that references my initial table, and breaks down every ShortNameEN, the following way:

Example for ProductId = 123, ShortNameEN = 'PRINTER'

```
ProductId | NameFragment
123       | PRINTER
123       | RINTER
123       | INTER
123       | NTER
123       | TER
123       | ER
123       | R
```

Trigger on the Product table will sync the ProductNameFragments table.

This way I can join my two tables, and query without the initial wildcard.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Product p, ProductNameFragment pnf
WHERE p.Id = pnf.ProductId
AND pnf.NameFragment LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

First tests show that this dramatically improves my search query performance.

**Question 2:** Should I use a regular index, or a clustered index on ProductNameFragment? And how will this affect performance when updating/deleting/inserting products?
When updating one product name, this could potentially lead to 50 deletes and 50 inserts in the ProductNameFragments table. Can I force the index only to be updated once?

In the end, I would prefer not to use the 'trigram' solution, because of the complexity. So any tips or tricks are more than welcome.

Thx in advance

Steven

Comment: I would start with full text search:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I recommend using Full Text Search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search

Comment: Fulltext searches are more suitable for searching full words. 'Printer' might not be the best example here, but search on %int% should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Without full-text search, a full index scan will be required.  About the only think you can do to optimize leading wild card scan performance is to use a legacy SQL_* collation instead of a Windows collation. The legacy collations have less overhead due to simpler, albeit less robust, comparison rules.

I suggest a clustered index on the `ProductFragment` table `ProductID` column to optimize product-level operations. Alternatively, a clustered primary key on the `ProductID` and `NameFragment` natural key would optimize the insert/update/delete operations and ensure data integrity.

Comment: At this point, use of BINARY collation will speed up even more

Comment: @StevenQ, agreed a binary collation will be fastest. If a case-insensitive search with a binary collation is desired, it will be necessary to store the name fragments in a consistent case (upper like the sample data) and specify the search string in same case.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the main purposes of full-text search (FTS) are:

1. Stemming (search by root, discarding pre/suffixes, inflections, etc.), with regard to a particular language;
2. Indexing of binary formats (such as text in DOC/X, PDF, and other similar file formats).

The FTS engine shipped with Microsoft SQL Server doesn't have a leading wildcard search, so don't bother.

The solution you mentioned is, AFAIK, the only one that will give you any kind of decent performance for leading wildcards. Moreover, any FTS products that would claim this kind of functionality will implement this very 'trigram' algorithm behind the curtains.

For your own implementation, a table such as this would be a good start:

```
create table dbo.TextFragments (
  TextFragment nvarchar(...) not null, -- Maximum size depends on your data
  LanguageId int not null,
  EntityId int not null,
  RowId bigint not null,
  constraint [PK_TextFragments] primary key (TextFragment, LanguageId, EntityId, RowId)
);
```

I have put all languages together into a single table; without that, adding new language to your system would become rather convoluted. Of course, you will need a language lookup table, too.

The `EntityId` field allows you to index data from different tables. If you have exactly one table and don't plan to index any others, you can drop the field.

The `RowId` field stores the identifier of the row in a corresponding table that matches the fragment. Of course, you can adjust the data type or add other columns to make it work with your system.

As it has been suggested by others, you might want to play with collations and casing of the text fragment to optimise the search a bit further. In the future, if / when your system will store more entries (say 100M) you might want to introduce partitioning to keep sizes of a single section within reasonable limits. Right now it's peanuts, so don't worry about that, or any filesystem issues.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Indeed, i did not mention FTS because i already ran into these limitation. The purpose of my question was more to receive tips and tricks on indexes, and filesystem optimisations for sql server finetuning.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try adding an extra columns with a palindromes and replace like %keyword% query with LIKE 'keyword%' OR LIKE 'droweyk%'. Which is also a hack